# Visual Studio unit testing - how to access external files?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have data files used as input to my unit tests. These files are quite big and I don't want to copy them each time unit tests are executed. Tests are executed without deployment. So I can just put them into folder under my solution, and... how to obtain path to my solution (or test project source code) when unit test is executing?

Answer (score 4):

Because you can run a test project in different ways (TD.NET, Visual Studio, R# etc.), the path used to reference the tests can change.

For this reason, I embed test needed files in my test assembly and draw them out from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

in your tests to get the path of the assembly containing the unit tests.

Comment: It gives location of the unit test's binary file, but I still don't know path to the solution's root.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` during a unit tests points to a temporary testing folder - the original poster needs to access files in his project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, make the location of the files configurable (and testable).

Then either, set it in the unit testing code or set it thru some config file.